# use ((c1^c2) & ~32) to test if c1 and c2 are the same character in different case

Tags: c, operators

I saw some code like this

```
if( ((c1^c2) & ~32)==0 )
{
  ...
}
```

In this snippet the code likely mean that if the `if` statement is true, then `c1` and `c2` are the same character **in different case**, meaning that one of those is +32 or -32 away from the other. Why is that?

I did test myself and discover that in some case it is true while in others not:

```
printf("%d", (65^97)& ~32);   //output is 0. right
printf("%d", (97^65)& ~32);   //output is 0. right

printf("%d", (50^82)& ~32);   //output is 64!! not the same though 82-50=32
```

Why is that? what is the magic in it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(c1^c2) & ~32)` xors `c1` and `c2`, the result contains the bits that are in both characters and `&` with `~32` clears (ignores) the bit 5. (It is zeroed whether it was same in both or not). Comparing this with zero, checks if all the bits other than `bit 5` are same.

This can be used to check if 2 letters are equal ignoring their case in ascii representation if you are sure that atleast `c1` or `c2` is a valid latin character(a-z, A-Z).

To understand this, let's pick 2 characters with different case and compare them:

```
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
a      | 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
         |   x   |   |   |   |   |   |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
A      | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
a ^ A  | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
32     | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
~32    | 1 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
&      | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
       +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
```

You can try the same with `j` v/s `J` or `t` v/s `z`.
So there is no magic involved, only this logic.

Sometimes this condition is also written as:

```
if (ch1 == ch2 || (ch1 ^ 32) == ch2)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: So I can only use it to compare between valid latin character? Is there any other way to break this limit?

Comment: You can write `if( isalpha(c1) && ((c1^c2) & ~32)==0 )` or `if(tolower(c1) == tolower(c1)`

Comment: sure it would work to use function in standard lib . But can i do it in the "logic" way as the code above?

Comment: `if( ( ('a' <= ch1 && ch1 <= 'z') || ('A' <= ch1 && ch1 <= 'Z') ) && (c1^c2) & ~32)==0)` I would use this one if my company pays me to clutter the code.

Comment: @walkerlala I can suggest another approach. `char isAlpha[256] = {0};` Initialize this once as: `for(char ch1 = 'a', ch2 = 'A'; ch1 <= 'z'; ++ch1, ++ch2) isAlpha[ch1] = isAlpha[ch2] = 1;`, later your code looks as: `if( isAlpha[ch1] && (c1^c2) & ~32)==0)`. This is more readable, less prone to error but requires extra memory.